# how do I filter a table by multiple columns onkeyup with java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

am trying to filter a table  by multiple columns onkeyup with java script
am able to do this when i specify the column index for only one td like say

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
```

but the  filter does not work when I try add anothor column index like say

```
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1][2];
```

the issue is I cant figure out how to be able to do this by specifying two or more column index for the same tr

this is my code

```
1 function myFunction() {
2  // Declare variables
3    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
4    input = document.getElementById('<%=txtsearch1.ClientID%>');
5    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
6    table = document.getElementById('<%=mygrid.ClientID%>');
7    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

8    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
9    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
10        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

11        if (td) {
12            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
13            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
14                tr[i].style.display = "";
15            } else {
16                tr[i].style.display = "none";
17            }
18        }
19    }
20 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,this is code :

// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++)
{

   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"); //Watch carefully this

 for(j=0;j<td.length;++j) // new loop
       {
          console.log(td[j]);
            if (td[j]) { //Change over here
              txtValue = td[j].textContent || td[j].innerText;
              console.log(txtValue);
              if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                 tr[i].style.display = "";
              } else {
                 tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
           }
      }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I dont get you please can you come again?

Comment: Below line in your code return array that is td

tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

Iterate td since it's array, what i mean loop through each items within td.

Comment: I have tried but it returns empty table (it hides all row) when I search

Comment: I figured it out, apply break within 1st if block.

What is happening over here is even though 1st column text matching condition the 2nd column text from same row which is not meeting filter criteria so it is(2nd column) is hiding row.

 if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {              
                 tr[i].style.display = "block";
                 break;
              }

Comment: great this is working now after applying the break thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add another loop for the tds as you're doing with the trs. like that -

```
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('<%=txtsearch1.ClientID%>');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById('<%=mygrid.ClientID%>');
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length; j++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];

            if (td) {
                txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried but it returns empty table (it hides all row) when I search

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the answer from [Altaf Khokhar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59286646/5068465) slightly with correct hiding values and fast escaping when  a hit is found.
I found that my header went missing, so I had to offset the tr index by 1.

```
     function myFunction() {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, filterelement;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
      // Should be offset 1 as first index is the header
      for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        filterelement = true;

        for (j = 0; j < tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td").length; j++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                filterelement = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (filterelement) {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        }
      }
    };
```